# Simple test cases in Haskell modules

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, testing

I want to write my own test cases in Haskell modules. Lets say I made a "range" module. I might want to check:

```
(range 1 2) + (range 3 5) == (range 1 5)
(range 1 4) + empty == (range 1 4)
```

etc.

I'd like to put these tests in modules, and perhaps some way to turn them on/off using a compiler flag.

I'm not currently really interested in some framework generating test cases for me, I'm happy to do that myself.

Comment: What's the question, exactly?

Comment: You can use cabal test suites to toggle your tests (http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#test-suites).

Comment: FWIW there are several packages on hackage to manipulate ranges (shameless plug: including my own, http://hackage.haskell.org/package/range-space, which allows for adding multi-dimensional ranges in sensible ways)

Answer (score 3):

Why not try the new hotness that is [Tasty](https://github.com/feuerbach/tasty). Tasty can be integrated with cabal for integrated building/testing.

```
import Test.Tasty
import Test.Tasty.HUnit

import My.Range.Module

main = defaultMain unitTests

unitTests = testGroup "Unit tests" [
  testCase "Adding Continuous Ranges" $
    (range 1 2) + (range 3 5) @?= (range 1 5),
  testCase "Adding an empty Range" $
    (range 1 4) + empty @?= (range 1 4)]
```

There are command line options

```
% ./test --help
Mmm... tasty test suite

Usage: ex [-p|--pattern ARG] [-l|--list-tests] [-j|--num-threads ARG]
          [-q|--quiet] [--hide-successes] [--smallcheck-depth ARG]
          [--quickcheck-tests ARG] [--quickcheck-replay ARG]
          [--quickcheck-max-size ARG] [--quickcheck-max-ratio ARG]

Available options:
  -h,--help                Show this help text
  -p,--pattern ARG         Select only tests that match pattern
  -l,--list-tests          Do not run the tests; just print their names
  -j,--num-threads ARG     Number of threads to use for tests execution
  -q,--quiet               Do not produce any output; indicate success only by
                           the exit code
  --hide-successes         Do not print tests that passed successfully
  --smallcheck-depth ARG   Depth to use for smallcheck tests
  --quickcheck-tests ARG   Number of test cases for QuickCheck to generate
  --quickcheck-replay ARG  Replay token to use for replaying a previous test run
  --quickcheck-max-size ARG
                           Size of the biggest test cases quickcheck generates
  --quickcheck-max-ratio ARG
                           Maximum number of discared tests per successful test
                           before giving up
```

You can use the `--pattern` option to select only specific tests to run